# Managing memory in 3d array of polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, polymorphism

I've got a question here that someone might be able to help out with.
If you can, many thanks!

I'm trying to store a three dimensional array containing many, small objects.
All of these object classes will inherit from one parent class.

Ideally I'm looking at a 32x32x32 array of objects, and objects are not likely to exceed 8 bytes each.
So, 32768 objects at up to 8 bytes each = 256kb

However some of them will NOT require 8 bytes of data, and will only require, in some cases, a single byte of data.

The problem is that each of these objects will have a distinct set of behaviours based on what they are. So if I call (obj.print()) each one will behave differently.

This in itself is easily enough solved with creating subclasses that inherit the generic interface class. However because they're being stored in large quantities in a 3d array, storing them as pointers automatically adds another 4 bytes of overhead - 8 bytes for the data type, and 4 bytes for the pointer to it.
On average, even if some of the objects are less than 8 bytes, the memory overhead is still going to add at least 30% higher usage.

That in itself isn't a *huge* issue, until I start storing many of these data blocks - then memory becomes a rather serious concern.

It seems from a long term maintainability and code management point of view, this really is the best way to do it. But I come to the smart folks here to see if you've got any pearls of wisdom you could share! :)

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: You could implement your own discriminated union space-efficiently.

Comment: that the content is polymorphic, referencing instances of different derivations from the same common base *in the same container*, is going to somewhat limit your options.

Comment: A polymorphic object that occupies one single byte is a theoretical possibility not prohibited by the standard, but you will have to look *a bit* for an implementation that can actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on runtime polymorphism, I have bad news for you - you will be  using pointers, which will add some memory overhead.

As far as 1-byte polymorphic structures go, there is a vtable pointer added when your member functions are virtual, so I'm not entirely sure how you would go about implementing them.

If you could drop the polymorphism, the std::tuple might be an alternative. There might be trouble with iterating over it, or initializing it with 32^3 elements, but it might be doable using templates, depending on what you might want to achieve.